# Intellisense does not work properly VS2015 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have a project in Visual studio 2015 using visual basic. I have Windows 10. My project includes connection with database. My problem is, that when i write a method i expect from intellisense to give me more values than is actually giving. For example i give you this line of code:    `adpSongs.SelectCommand.Connection = cManager.con`                         The adpSongs is the sql adapter . This line of code is totally accepted and my programm works in full functionality. But **SelectCommand.Connection** are not given by intellisense actually what i get by many components are the submethods Equals, GetHashCode, getType, To string. I have tried : delete suo file , reopen, recreate , rebuild , tools->oprions->textEditor->languages->auto list members and parameters information checked. I have update 2 but i cant move on update 3 because of disk space. pls help!

Comment: Check the type of `adpSongs`. It sounds like it is probably an `Object` and so will not have what you're looking for

Comment: Dim adpSongs = New SqlDataAdapter so ok is considered an object but intellisense should have given to me more option when i write **adpSongs.** than 4. My colleagues have more results by intellisense

Comment: That doesn't matter. Check your project settings to see if `Option Infer` is off. If it is then you need to do `Dim adpSongs As New SqlDataAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `Option Infer` turned on for your project, everything defaults to a type of `Object` unless specified.

Using
`Dim adpSongs = New SqlDataAdapter` will not actually give it a type of `SqlDataAdapter`.

The solutions:

`Dim adpSongs As New SqlDataAdapter`

or slightly longer, but with clearer assignment.

`Dim adpSongs as SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter`

Or turn `Option Infer` on in your project (not always recommended)